# Will this one-switch resonant topology work?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, nmos, single-ended, powermosfet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdixpP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will this thing work? I do not mind the horrendous amount of interference this may produce. Principle of operation is:

1. Switch-on causes C1 to conduct some current into base of Q1.
2. When C1 is charged, Q2 turns off. Uce is limited by D2.
3. IRF840 turns on, causing L2 and C2 to resonate.
4. The voltage change on C1 causes Q1 and M1 to turn on and off synchronously with the resonance of L2-C2.
5. The voltage reverses polarity, causing D1 to not conduct for 10ms.

Comment: I fixed the schematic as best I could. Check the 4-wire connection at Q1's collector to see if that's what you intended. Your neighbours might have other opinions about the horrendous amount of interference this may produce.

Comment: What does "work" mean in this circuit? what do you intend it to do?

Comment: I edited the schematic to eliminate the short between Q1 B-C.  Note that the connection from Q1-B to C1 needs a series resistor or Q1 will be destroyed pretty much immediately.